# Unable to change the innerHTML of a <p/> tag in PHP

Tags: php

I am learning PHP and trying to change the `innerHtml` of a `<p/>` tag using PHP.

The problem is that I don't know why one of my PHP variables is working while the other is not.

The problem I am running into is within the last `if` statement; the `$check` variable is not being printed, however when replaced it with another variable `$pin`, it worked.

### Code

```
</header>

<head>
    <h1> MD5 cracker</h1>
</head>

<body>

    <p>This application takes an MD5 hash of a four digit pin and check all 10,000 possible four digit PINs to determine the PIN.</p><br/>

    <p id='deb'>Debug Output:<br/></p>
    <p id='pin'>PIN: Not found </p>

    <form method='POST'>
        <input type='text' name='md5' value="">
        <input type='submit' value='Crack MD5'>
    </form>

    <?php
        $count=0;
        $pin_list=array();
        $pin_digits=array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
        if (isset($_POST['md5'])) {
            $md5= $_POST['md5'];



        foreach ($pin_digits as $d1){
            foreach ($pin_digits as $d2){
                foreach ($pin_digits as $d3){
                    foreach ($pin_digits as $d4){
                        $pin= $d1 . $d2.$d3.$d4;
                        $check=hash('md5',$pin);


                        if ( $check==$md5){
                            echo "<script> 
                            document.getElementById('pin').innerHTML='PIN: '+$pin; 
                                </script>";
                            break;
                                            }
                        if ($count<15)    {
                            echo "<script> 
                        document.getElementById('deb').innerHTML=$check; 
                                </script>";
                            $count+=1;

                                            }

                                     }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

    ?>


</body>
```

Comment: Please tell us what it is you're trying to accomplish. We can't tell you what's wrong if we don't have anything to compare to.

Comment: i am trying to change the text of the paragraph with the id='deb' to equal the content of the php variable $check.  see the code below                                    if ($count<15)    {
                            echo "<script> 
                        document.getElementById('deb').innerHTML=$check; 
                                </script>";
                            $count+=1;

                                            }

Comment: You have your first `if ( $check==$md5){ ...` and `break;` inside of that `if`. That means when succeed program flow jumps out of the `foreach` loop and neve get to your line with 2nd `if` statement `if ($count<15) {`. Do you understand that?

Comment: PHP isn't changing the innerHTML, javascript is. It would be easier just to run if statements in your PHP and echo the results

Comment: You need single quotes around `$check` i.e. `document.getElementById('deb').innerHTML='$check';`

Comment: perfect, single quote is what was missing. it works now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you forget quotes on `.innerHTML='$check';`

```
<body>

    <p>This application takes an MD5 hash of a four digit pin and check all 10,000 possible four digit PINs to determine the PIN.</p><br/>

    <p id='deb'>Debug Output:<br/></p>
    <p id='pin'>PIN: Not found </p>

    <form method='POST'>
        <input type='text' name='md5' value="">
        <input type='submit' value='Crack MD5'>
    </form>

    <?php
        $count=0;
        $pin_list=array();
        $pin_digits=array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
        if (isset($_POST['md5'])) {
            $md5= $_POST['md5'];



        foreach ($pin_digits as $d1){
            foreach ($pin_digits as $d2){
                foreach ($pin_digits as $d3){
                    foreach ($pin_digits as $d4){
                        $pin= $d1 . $d2.$d3.$d4;
                        $check=hash('md5',$pin);


                        if ( $check==$md5){
                            echo "<script> 
                            document.getElementById('pin').innerHTML='PIN: '+$pin; 
                                </script>";
                            break;
                                            }
                        if ($count<15)    {
                            echo "<script> 
                        document.getElementById('deb').innerHTML='$check'; 
                                </script>";
                            $count+=1;

                                            }

                                     }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

    ?>


</body>
```

Comment: if ( $check==$md5){
                            echo "<script> 
                            document.getElementById('pin').innerHTML='PIN: '+$pin; 
                                </script>";
                            break;

Comment: in the above code, i did not have single quote around the php variable $pin and it seems to work. i wonder why?

Comment: Yes, there you also need a quote but because of this condition `if ($check==$md5)` is false and the `document.getElementById('pin').innerHTML='PIN: '+$pin;` does not execute so that you did not get any problem

Answer (score 0):

JS code should be like `document.getElementById('str').innerHTML = 'string';`, so update your php source then everything ok. Like

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('pin').innerHTML='PIN: {$pin}';</script>";
echo "<script>document.getElementById('deb').innerHTML='{$check}';</script>";
```